# How to sort overflowed short signed ints in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a collection of files, with timestamps and indices in their filenames.  The files are generated on a second, or sub-second basis, so the index is the unique identifier, not the timestamp.  I'd like to sort them by index.

HOWEVER...Foresight might not have been the strong suit of the person who wrote the code to produce these filenames, because they were made with short signed ints, and there are over 32K files in a directory.  As such, it overflows, and the files in the correct order go like this.  This is in a text file with the fields parsed (including some that are irrelevant to this subject) and printed separately:

```
....
210717 32763 0 dark 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_17_dark_integ_300_img_32763.raw
210717 32764 0 n850 700 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_17_n850_integ_700_img_32764.raw
210718 32765 0 blue 250 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_18_blue_integ_250_img_32765.raw
210718 32766 0 red 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_18_red_integ_300_img_32766.raw
210719 32767 0 n750 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_19_n750_integ_300_img_32767.raw
210719 -32768 0 green 250 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_19_green_integ_250_img_-32768.raw
210720 -32767 0 red 250 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_20_red_integ_250_img_-32767.raw
210720 -32766 0 red 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_20_red_integ_300_img_-32766.raw
210721 -32765 0 dark 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_21_dark_integ_300_img_-32765.raw
....
```

But they are sorted like this:

```
....
210717 32763 0 dark 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_17_dark_integ_300_img_32763.raw
210717 32764 0 n850 700 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_17_n850_integ_700_img_32764.raw
210718 32765 0 blue 250 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_18_blue_integ_250_img_32765.raw
210718 32766 0 red 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_18_red_integ_300_img_32766.raw
210719 32767 0 n750 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_19_n750_integ_300_img_32767.raw
210719 -32768 0 green 250 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_19_green_integ_250_img_-32768.raw
210720 -32766 0 red 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_20_red_integ_300_img_-32766.raw
210720 -32767 0 red 250 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_20_red_integ_250_img_-32767.raw
210721 -32765 0 dark 300 Feb_03_2013_time_21_07_21_dark_integ_300_img_-32765.raw
....
```

Note that it sorts correctly by timestamp, but post-overflow, if more than one file is made in a second, they're sorted backwards.

Is there a sorting algorithm I can call in bash to sort lines in a file formatted like this in the way that I want?  I'm currently using the command

```
cat tempfilelists/unsorted_list.txt | sort -n > tempfilelists/sorted_list.txt
```

(This is an intermediate step, BTW, afterwards I iterate through and assign them a new, properly sized index.)

Comment: It might be easier to use something like awk to simply fix the values in-place and then sort. You could even pad out the other values at the same time if you wanted to. `awk '$2 < 0 {n=$2; n=n + (2 * 32768); sub("_"$2"\\.", "_"n".", $NF); $2=n}7'` or something like that.

Comment: ...That was easy, and I shoulda thought of it.  I am not much of a bash ninja, and I don't really know how awk works.  I *should* learn it one of these days, but I just did this instead: if [ $index -lt 0 ]; then index=$(($index+2*32768)); fi  Anyway, thanks!  If you make this an answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier to just fix the values in place then sort.

Something like this should do that:

```
awk '$2 < 0 {n=$2; n=n + (2 * 32768); sub("_"$2"\\.", "_"n".", $NF); $2=n}7
```

Then you can just sort normally. If you wanted to pad out the fields you could do that in that single awk pass too.